# iOS client, Server in C++?

Tags: ios, sockets, client

I'm new to network programming. This is probably a stupid question, would it be okay for my server to be in C++ for my iOS application?

Comment: Is the server a separate piece of hardware or is it an iOS device?

Comment: I was thinking a completely separate hardware, on its own.
Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not care what your server is programmed with. You can use whatever you feel comfortable with. Remember, you aren't going to be sending executable code to the server - you are just going to be sending requests and the server will send a response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your server can be written in *any way you want*, provided you define the correct protocol (method of communication) between your iPhone app (client) and the server.

XML, JSON, HTTP POST or GET's, whatever.  It should all work, provided you code both sides correctly.